# Sum eigenvalues for two matrices with same eigenvector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a square matrix A and its square, A^2, are the eigenvalues of A+A^2 the sum of the matrices eigenvalues? I know that the two share the same eigenvector, but wasn't sure if it meant we could simply add the eigenvalues to find A+A^2's eigenvalues.

Comment: I was looking to find the eigenvalues of (A+A^2), but did not know if I could make the assumption that their eigenvalues can be summed; two very different approaches to the problem based on this assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In particular, the eigenvalues of $A^2$ are of the form $\lambda^2$ and the eigenvalues of $A^2 + A$ are of the form $\lambda^2 + \lambda$, where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. More generally, for a polynomial $p$, the eigenvalues of $p(A)$ are of the form $p(\lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.